# Datatables library can consume cpu?

Tags: html, css, datatable

I'm using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) to organize some records (aprox 50.000) in a table, but I didn't download it, I'm just using the css and js links that they gives us:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css">

<!-- datatables con bootstrap -->
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>

<!-- Buttons -->
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
```

And because I'm having 100% cpu usage and it doesn't decrease, my queries are well optimized and I use Indexes in the tables, maybe this is a problem.

So, to remove this option, does cpu usage have to do with datatables?

Comment: I don't think I have understood your specific question... And there is insufficient information provided (CPU usage where? In the browser? In the server?). But... if you are trying to use DataTables to load and render 50,000 records, it's possible your browser is overloaded. You can test with smaller amounts to see what happens - for example, try 5,000 records. If 5,000 records work OK, then consider using [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side), where you only ever pass one page of records at a time to the browser (so, maybe only 10 records or 100 records).

Comment: But, this may have nothing to do with DataTables - it is impossible to say, based on the facts you have provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

DataTables is supposed to be able to handle local processing of quite a few elements. How are you supplying the data? If it's all inside the DOM, I could see it slowing your computer down if you have old hardware. Otherwise, it's probably something else.

Comment: So not, I can discar Datatables for this, thanks